# flextable: systematically change multiple headers' labels

Tags: r, header, flextable

I'm looking to change the `S_1` through `S_4` here with a one-liner, instead of typing them all out in `set_header_label`.

[image]`

how I made up `ft1`

```
ft1 <- head(iris) %>%
  flextable() %>%
set_header_labels(
  values = list(
    Sepal.Length = "S_1",
    Sepal.Width = "S_2",
    Petal.Length = "S_3",
    Petal.Width = "S_4"
  )
)
```

The rough idea of the one-liner

```
ft1 %>%
  set_header_labels(
  values = list(list(S_1:S_4) = list(paste("\U03A3", c(1:4), sep = "_"))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one approach is to create a named list separately, and then use in `set_header_labels`. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)

my_list <- setNames(as.list(paste0("S_", 1:4)), names(iris[1:4]))

ft1 <- head(iris) %>%
  flextable() %>%
  set_header_labels(values = my_list)
```